# Java RMI: concurrency support

Tags: java, concurrency, jakarta-ee, rmi, concurrent-programming

I am developing a multiplayer card game with a P2P architecture, it isn't a my decision, the project has been commissioned by the professor of Distributed System course at my University.

Another constraint imposed by the professor is to use Java RMI technology to implement the communication layer between the players.

i would know if Java RMI manages concurrency "out of the box", in other words I would know if when I invoke a method on a remote object, the object is automatically "locked" and no objects can concurrently invoke the same method.

Could to declare methods as synchronized be a good solution?

Thanks

Comment: Depends on the RMI provider ... but default is multi-threaded and thus is able to invoke the same method concurrently. That being said, I think it's silly to blindly synchronize on a method -- it is *objects* and *usage of such* which need to be protected.

Comment: I assert that there are no RMI providers that are single threaded. The RMI specification basically says that you cannot assume it is single-threaded, so you have to take care of synchronization yourself. I also assert that there is actually no such thing as an RMI provider, RMI not having an SPI architecture: there are only implementations of the entire JDK.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calling a method on a remote object does not lock the object.

Declaring a method to be synchronized is one way to control access.  However simply declaring all of your methods on all of your remote-accessible objects to be synchronized is a bad idea.  Indeed, depending on the details of what you are doing it could create unnecessary concurrency bottlenecks and/or the risk of [deadlocks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deadlock).  You need to think more carefully about the behavior of the objects and the interactions.

Answer (score 1):

Synchronizing your method is a good start. There is a performance penalty for doing this, but in your case this is perfectly fine.

Take a look at this [Java RMI and synchronized methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3507253/java-rmi-and-synchronized-methods)