# RMI and threading on weblogic

Tags: ajax, weblogic, rmi

I have a web app implemented with SmartGWT (Ajax) and deployed to WebLogic 12c. Due to difficulties resolving classpath issues integrating one particular custom API, I'm investigating the suitability of using Java RMI to access this API. My question is, since my app is completely asynchronous, is there a potential for threading issues when using RMI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RMI is not 'completely asynchronous': it is fundamentally a request/response protocol. There is always a 'potential for threading issues when using RMI'. There are no guarantees about the RMI threading behaviour. Any synchronization required is therefore 100% up to you.

Comment: Thanks. I see now there is plenty of discussion about these issues already [link] http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2275868/java-rmi-and-thread-synchronization-questions[/link]. Don't know how I missed them earlier.